# Grails collect() using each{} of bytes

Tags: grails

How can I get each image to `encodeBase64` in my collection? Animal has many Images, and Image belongs to Animal.

```
def a = Animal.findAll().collect() { Animal an ->
    [id          : an.id,
     image       : an.imagens.caminho.each {(new File(it).bytes.encodeBase64().toString()) }
    ]
}
```

In my `JSON` only returns the path, not the bytes. How can I fix it?

Comment: Unless I am missing something you should be able to simply change `an.imagens.caminho.each` to `an.imagens.caminho.collect` and get the expected behavior.

Comment: No worries, added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `collect` them into a list instead of using `each`. So your code should look like this:

```
def a = Animal.findAll().collect() { Animal an ->
    [id: an.id,
     image: an.imagens.caminho.collect {(new File(it).bytes.encodeBase64().toString()) }
    ]
}
```